# How do I capture a reference to super and pass it on?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I have a subclass with a common pattern in many of its methods:

```
if some_condition
  (real code goes here)
else
  super
end
```

Ideally I would like to encapsulate it in something like:

```
def if_some_condition
  if some_condition
    yield
  else
    (calling method's super)
  end
end
```

Is there any way I capture the calling method's `super` so that I can call it in the `else` branch of `if_some_condition`?

(Before suggesting the use of another subclass, note that `some_condition` may change frequently over the lifetime of objects in that class.)

---

EDIT:

A possible solution is:

```
def if_some_condition(&b)
  if some_condition
    yield
  else
    b.send(:binding).eval('super')
  end
end
```

I would rather avoid the use of `eval` if possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should never call super from outside of the class... maybe you could add a boolean parameter "super", when "super" is true you call the super method

You can see the result here : http://repl.it/KOd

```
class My_base_class
  def methode_one(argument={})
    puts "yabadabadou"
  end
end

class My_sub_Class < My_base_class
  def methode_one(argument={})
    if(argument[:super])
      puts "taratata"
    else
      super
    end 
  end
end


def if_some_condition(b)
  if 1==1
    b.methode_one({:super=>false})
  else
     b.methode_one({:super=>true})
  end
end

def if_some_other_condition(b)
  if 1==0
    b.methode_one({:super=>false})
  else
    b.methode_one({:super=>true})
  end
end
```